# How SBC instruction works in this case?

Tags: assembly, 6502

Why the value of c flag is 0 in this case?

```
SEC 
LDA #0 
SBC #1
```

Since the C flag is 1 then borrow is 0 shouldn't the C flag remain 1

Comment: `SBC` calculates 0 minus 1, which results in a borrow. So `SBC` leaves A=$FF and C=0. Wouldn't you agree?

Answer (score 3):

Normally x - y = x + (-y) = x + ~y + 1

Documentation says the carry bit is a not borrow, and to set to 1 for a normal subtract, so the carry in is not inverted on this architecture (some architectures the carry bit is a borrow if 1 and is inverted on the way into an sbc).

so 0 - 1 = 0 + 0xFE + 1

```
         1
  00000000
+ 11111110
==========
```

fill it in

```
 000000001
  00000000
+ 11111110
========== 
  11111111
```

result 0xFF, carry out is 0 which indicates a borrow.

Comment: The designers chose the "inverted borrow" not to be deliberately confusing but to make the ALU simpler. Using this method, subtraction is simply inverting the bits of the second operand and then doing an addition.

Comment: right, invert carry in and second operand.  but in general folks should know that some architectures the carry FLAG for subtract might be 1 is borrow 0 is not borrow (indicating the carry out to carry flag is inverted).   and I assume in those architectures that is so they can say it is a borrow bit which is less confusing than inverted borrow bit.

Answer (score 1):

> The carry works as an inverse borrow. i.e., to subtract, first set the carry. If the carry is cleared by the operation, a borrow has occurred.

[c64os.com instruction set](https://c64os.com/post/6502instructions)